# How do I display two columns with multiple values and separate the occurances with a WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, where-clause

This is my SQL query I am trying to select the names of employees from the employee table 'T' as trainer and 'S' as student. Where each student is linked to a trainer.

SQL query:

```
SELECT
    cc.CourseName,
    FORMAT(cs.StartDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy') AS 'Start Date',
    FORMAT(cs.EndDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy') AS 'End Date',
    a.AcademyName,
    r.RoomName,
    (SELECT e.FirstName + ' ' + e.LastName WHERE e.EmployeeType = 'T') AS 'Trainer',
    (SELECT e.FirstName + ' ' + e.LastName WHERE e.EmployeeType = 'S') AS 'Student'
FROM 
    Employees e
INNER JOIN 
    CourseScheduleTrainers cst ON e.EmployeeID = cst.EmployeeID
INNER JOIN 
    CourseScheduleAttendees csa ON cst.TrainerID = csa.TrainerID
INNER JOIN 
    CourseCatalog cc ON csa.CourseCatalogID = cc.CourseCatalogID
INNER JOIN 
    CourseSchedule cs ON cc.CourseScheduleID = cs.CourseScheduleID
INNER JOIN 
    Rooms r ON cs.RoomsID = r.RoomsID
INNER JOIN 
    Academies a ON r.AcademyID = a.AcademyID;
```

This is what it is returning:

[image]

And this is an ERD of the database I am am trying to create. Essentially Course Attendees can also be classed as employees and they are labelled using the Employee Type

Entity Relationship Diagram:

[image]

I thought it was a simple case of sub querying but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: How are students reflected in course attendees? I can see how trainers are.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Your "I am trying to select" is unclear. No one could write your desired query from that. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) [ask] For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization.

Comment: @philipxy Hi, apologies I'm still quite new to the site. However, my query is posted as code. I was simply trying to see if the formatting was causing an issue, so it was the only code snippet I felt relevant. The only images that I have posted is the table returned when the query is executed as well as the entity relationship diagram and I believe the formatting is in line with the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that you referenced. If there is anything that I have overlooked please let me know as I'm still learning.

Comment: We cannot cut & paste & run, it's not minimal, no one could take your description & know what your code should do, etc etc per my comment & the [mre] link. PS  Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Make each post self-contained.

Comment: @Parfait Thank you! I would need to include an ***EmployeeID*** in the ***CourseScheduleAttendees*** as right now there is no relationship between the two tables. I originally had ***AttendeeID*** within the ***Employees*** table but this broke it out of normalisation and I was returning foreign key constraints. The way that the tables are named could be changed but that's how the question was laid out so it is confusing. Essentially attendees are the students and are also classed as employees, the way that they are separated in the ***Employee*** table is via the ***EmployeeType*** attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Consider joining ***Employees*** twice and re-order the `FROM` and `JOIN` clauses to start with the main granular table, ***CourseScheduleAttendees***, where other tables serve as lookups in a hub-spoke fashion:

```
SELECT cc.CourseName
       ,FORMAT(cs.StartDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy') AS 'Start Date' 
       ,FORMAT(cs.EndDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy') AS 'End Date' 
       ,a.AcademyName 
       ,r.RoomName
       ,t.FirstName + ' ' + t.LastName AS 'Trainer' 
       ,s.FirstName + ' ' + s.LastName AS 'Student' 
FROM CourseScheduleAttendees csa
INNER JOIN CourseScheduleTrainers cst
   ON csa.TrainerID = cst.TrainerID  
INNER JOIN Employees t
   ON cst.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID 
   AND t.EmployeeType = 'T'
INNER JOIN Employees s
   ON csa.AttendeeID = s.EmployeeID 
   AND s.EmployeeType = 'S'
INNER JOIN CourseCatalog cc 
   ON csa.CourseCatalogID = cc.CourseCatalogID 
INNER JOIN CourseSchedule cs 
   ON cc.CourseScheduleID = cs.CourseScheduleID 
INNER JOIN Rooms r 
   ON cs.RoomsID = r.RoomsID 
INNER JOIN Academies a 
   ON r.AcademyID = a.AcademyID;
```